# I am attempting to make a 2D platformer on Unity but my character keeps flying to side without any input from the controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class Playerovement : MonoBehaviour
{
PlayerInputActions controls;
public CharacterController2D controller;
public float runSpeed = 40f;
float horizontalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;

void Awake () {
    controls = new PlayerInputActions();
    controls.Control.Jump.performed += ctx => Jump();
    controls.Control.Horizontal.performed += horizontalMove => Move();

}

void Jump() {        
    jump = true;
}
void Move() {
     controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, jump);
}

void OnEnable() {
    controls.Control.Enable();
}

void OnDisable() {
    controls.Control.Disable();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    jump = false;   
}
}
```

That is my code. The character controller is linked HERE (https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Character-Controller/blob/master/CharacterController2D.cs). Please help as my character keeps flying away.

Comment: Did you debug it yet?  Do you have any details to report at all?  The character only moves if targetVelocity changes, targetVelocity only changes if Move is called with non-zero move, and Move is only called with horizontalMove value which is zero. And I don't see any code that modifies horizontalMove So we I think we need more details.